# React Native: Could not determine java version from '15'

Tags: java, android, react-native, android-studio

After running this command `npx react-native run-android` I am getting this error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine java version from '15'.
```

When I run this  `java -version`

I got this:

```
java version "15" 2020-09-15
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 15+36-1562)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 15+36-1562, mixed mode, sharing)
```